# modification in UCF file in Xilinx xps

Tags: xilinx

In my ucf file in xps except to the clock of Microblaze I have to add one more clock of my design. I'm not able to understand how to do that.
It's giving me warning like:

> WARNING:ConstraintSystem:56 - Constraint  [system.ucf(13)]: Unable to find an active 'TNM' or 'TimeGrp'
>   constraint named 'clk'.

Here is my ucf file which is giving warning.

```
NET "CLK_N" LOC = AD11  |  IOSTANDARD = DIFF_SSTL15;

NET "CLK_P" LOC = AD12  |  IOSTANDARD = DIFF_SSTL15;


NET RESET LOC = "AB7"  |  IOSTANDARD = "LVCMOS15";

NET RS232_Uart_1_sin LOC = "M19"  |  IOSTANDARD = "LVCMOS25";

NET RS232_Uart_1_sout LOC = "K24"  |  IOSTANDARD = "LVCMOS25";

NET sm_fan_pwm_net_vcc LOC = "L26"  |  IOSTANDARD = "LVCMOS25";

NET "CLK" TNM_NET = sys_clk_pin;

TIMESPEC TS_sys_clk_pin = PERIOD sys_clk_pin 200000 kHz;

CONFIG DCI_CASCADE = "33 32 34";

#######custom ip clk##########

NET "clk" TNM_NET = "clk";

TIMESPEC TS_clk = PERIOD "clk" 5 ns HIGH 50 %;
```

How to define userip clock in ucf file? I want to give same clock to both Microblaze and my Verilog design.

Answer (score 1):

You have to assign the timing constraint to the clock pin. The clock pin is `clk_p` (we usually use positive pin for differential) while you try to assign the constraint to `clk`, which doesn't exist.

Moreover, you have duplicate constraint for the timing net `clk`. This UCF should work better:

```
NET "CLK_N" LOC = AD11  |  IOSTANDARD = DIFF_SSTL15;

NET "CLK_P" LOC = AD12  |  IOSTANDARD = DIFF_SSTL15;


NET RESET LOC = "AB7"  |  IOSTANDARD = "LVCMOS15";

NET RS232_Uart_1_sin LOC = "M19"  |  IOSTANDARD = "LVCMOS25";

NET RS232_Uart_1_sout LOC = "K24"  |  IOSTANDARD = "LVCMOS25";

NET sm_fan_pwm_net_vcc LOC = "L26"  |  IOSTANDARD = "LVCMOS25";

NET "CLK_P" TNM_NET = sys_clk_pin;

TIMESPEC TS_sys_clk_pin = PERIOD sys_clk_pin 200000 kHz;

CONFIG DCI_CASCADE = "33 32 34";
```

Comment: These two clocks are different in my design.As you said clk_n and clk_p are for differential clock (this clock is for microblaze ) but the timing net "clk" is a user-defined clock which i want to use in my ucf file.

how there are duplicate constraint on the timing net "clk" ???

Comment: What do you mean by "user-defined", you mean it's not a pin but the output of a PLL?

Comment: yes, i want this clock from the PLL on the board. In the datasheet of kintex 7 it is given that K28 and K29 are the user clock and I want to use those pin for my clock.

Comment: What board are you using? Is K28/K29 an input clock or you want to output a clock to those pins? On Xilinx, only the input clocks from a pin need a timing constraint. Any clock that passes through a PLL will have it's constraint automatically generated. In your sample UCF, the differential clock "CLK_P" didn't have a timing constraint, which is an error. Maybe it's not the problem you were looking for, but an issue that needs to be resolved nevertheless.

Comment: module mesh (input a,output reg b,input clock);   as this is my top module and this will be connected to microblaze ,how can i give clock to this module.I am using kintex 7 ,kc705.